# Ao invés de mapas como utilizar um vetor de struct para o problema em C++?

Tags: c++

Primeiramente tenho uma `struct`

```
strcuct Ficha{

      int resgistro;
      float pontuacao; 


 }Fichas[100];
```

é o seguinte vou ler de modo aleatório dados, mas um dado sempre na lista vai começar com o numero que não é inteiro ligado apontuação

```
0.5//pontuação
89933//registro 
49494
0.4
87474
0.6
89044
88443
86965
```

O problema é o seguinte 0.5 é dos dois registro que vem em baixo, 0.4 é apenas 87474 e depois vem 0.6 que pertence ao registro que tiverem em baixo da pontuação essa é a lógica.

Bom como dados estão num arquivo `txt`

Leitura

```
void lerArquvivo(){
    ifstream Arquivo;
    Arquivo.open("Regeistro.txt");
    char linha[10];
    float n;
    while(Arquivo.getline(linha,10)){

        Arquivo >> n;


        separa(n);

        }
     Arquivo.close();
     }
```

Então crie uma função que separa inteiro de não inteiro.

```
void separa(floar valor){
    int x = valor;
    float y = valor;
         if(x==y){
            //cout<<"Inteiro"<<endl;
                           }else{
                      //cout<<"Não e Inteiro"<<endl;
                            }
                        }
```

Ai vem, como tenho que armazenar no vetor Fichas `Fichas[i].registro`e `Fichas[i].pontuacao`, eu não consigo fazer para armazenar nos números da posição do vetor relacionada.

Como exemplo do problema.

```
posição do vetor      registro     pontuação
     0                   0            0.5
     1                  89487          0
     2                  78474          0
     3                    0            0.4
     .
     .......
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54599/discussion-on-question-by-rodolfo-ao-inves-de-mapas-como-utilizar-um-vetor-de-st)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que pode fazer para concluir a leitura é o seguinte:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <ifstream>

// ...

ifstream file("Registro.txt");
float pontuacao;
std::string line;
while (std::getline(file, line)) {
    if (line.find('.') != std::string::npos) { // Se contém um ponto, é float
        std::stringstream(line) >> pontuacao;
    } else {
        int registro;
        std::stringstream(line) >> registro;
        // Inserir (pontuacao, registro) na sua tabela
    }
}
```

Repare que aqui a pontuação é lida e persistida entre as linhas até que uma nova pontuação é encontrada. E quando um número de registro é lido, ele pareia com a pontuação mais recente lida.